# Is it possible to debug bash scripts line-by-line?

Tags: bash, debugging, line-by-line

I'll love something like Microsoft Visual Studio's line-by-line debugging in *bash*, with current variables values and so.

Is there any tool or way to do it? `set -x` and `set -v` are nice but not perfect.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Comment: Already seen. Doesn't covers line-by-line debugging, which is the whole point here. I've already searched alot and found nothing, which is why I came to SO.

Comment: No, the `set -x` (and `-n` and `-v`) options are basically what's available.

Comment: The linked question also refers [Bash Debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/) which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `bashdb`.

If it's installed on your system, see `man bashdb`.

If it's not installed, see http://bashdb.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use "bashdb" from http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/

Latest version at time of writing
http://sourceforge.net/projects/bashdb/files/bashdb/4.2-0.8/

If you are on a Mac (like I was) then you might need to install the GNU version of Bash.

I did that using "MacPorts"
http://www.macports.org/

Once you have MacPorts...

> port install bash

Then follow the instructions to

> ./configure (in bashdb unpacked directory)
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

Then add the folder where bashdb can be found in your PATH