# how can I run shell script line by line

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script and I want to debug it. What I want is that it display every line that is about to be executed I need to confirm this (by hitting enter or something like that)

So that I can see what is going to be executed and I can abort it in case it was anything dangerous

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889322/is-it-possible-to-debug-bash-scripts-line-by-line